# How to remove newline, whitespace and "\n" at the same time using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am going crazy here.
Using Angular and TypeScript, I fetch some data from OpenAI that when I console.log, it looks like this:

```
" {\n  joy: [\"yellow\", \"orange\", \"pink\"],\n  surprise: [\"blue\", \"purple\"],\n  fear: [\"black\", \"gray\"]\n};"
```

I need to remove newline, backslash and whitespace. I use JavaScript replace method to achieve this:

```
replace(/[\n\\ ]/g, '');
```

If you try to test this code in provided snippet, any JS console, or regex101 website, it will display the desired output. However, in my case, the output is always like this:

```
"{njoy:["yellow","orange","pink"],nsurprise:["blue","purple"],nfear:["black","gray"]n};"
```

Whitespace and \ get removed, but the "n" char stays. How to write regex so that output is

```
"{joy:["yellow","orange","pink"],surprise:["blue","purple"],fear:["black","gray"]};"
```

```js
const input = " {\n  joy: [\"yellow\", \"orange\", \"pink\"],\n  surprise: [\"blue\", \"purple\"],\n  fear: [\"black\", \"gray\"]\n};"
const output = input.replace(/[\n\\ ]/g, '');
console.log("Filtered string is", output);
```

Screenshot shows how the replace method looks in my code.

[image: How it looks in VS Code]

Comment: Can you try: `.replace(/\s|\\n?/g, '');`

Comment: `it looks like this` ... does your content literally have a `\n` inside the string?

Comment: Your code snippet works as you expect. Seems like, as @TimBiegeleisen suspects, your actual data has actual backslashes followed by the letter `n`, not newlines at all, in which case you need to match and replace that two character pattern, not just single characters in a class, e.g. `.replace(/(\\n|[\\ ])/g, '')`

Comment: Your snippet works good in Chrome  (output has no 'n' char).

Comment: "_Whitespace and \ get removed_" -  The backslash characters aren't part of your `input` string to begin with. They are part of the string _literal_ but not of the string value that the variable holds. The console can be deceiving when checking string values. (At least on Chrome) Right click the string and select "Copy string contents". Then paste it somewhere to see what it actually contains.

Comment: @anubhava, that worked. Thank you. Should've asked this hours ago.
@TimBiegeleisen Yes, it would literally have a \n, and that was the part that was confusing me. 
@Darth Yeah, snippet was working everywhere except in my project where I needed it. :)
@Ivar This is something to ponder about. When I do right click and copy string contents, I get normal string without any \n or \. Like this: `{joy: ["yellow", "orange", "pink"],surprise: ["blue", "purple"],fear: ["black", "gray"]};`
Thank you all for your quick comments!

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet works just fine. I'm guessing your *data* contains actual backslashes followed by the letter `n`, not newlines at all. In that case you need to match and replace that two character pattern, not just single characters in a class, e.g. `.replace(/(\\n|[\\ ])/g, '')`:

```js
// Using String.raw`` to get string with \n treated as raw characters, not newlines, just like if you read data of this form from a file or socket
const input = String.raw` {\n  joy: [\"yellow\", \"orange\", \"pink\"],\n  surprise: [\"blue\", \"purple\"],\n  fear: [\"black\", \"gray\"]\n};`;
const badoutput = input.replace(/[\n\\ ]/g, ''); // Only removes newlines, backslashes and spaces, not literal \n
console.log("Incorrectly filtered string is", badoutput);
const goodoutput = input.replace(/(\\n|[\n\\ ])/g, '');  // Removes literal \n, plus newlines, backslashes and spaces
console.log("Correctly filtered string is", goodoutput);
```

Comment: Note: If *any* whitespace should be stripped, `[\n\\ ]` can simplify to `\s`. But if weirder whitespace like tabs, vertical tabs and form feed characters (or Unicode whitespace like the non-breaking space, `\xa0`) can exist, and should not be stripped, stick to `[\n\\ ]`.

Comment: super valuable comment! thank you. This will be helpful for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

Looks like your input has literal `\n` and you want to remove `\` and whitespaces. Following should work for you:

```bash
text = text.replace(/\s|\\n?/g, '');
```

Where `\s` will match any whitespace including line breaks and `\\n?` will match literal `\n` and `\` which would be replaced with empty string.